# CSS selectors in firebug

Tags: javascript, css, firebug

Is there a JavaScript API I can pass any CSS selector I want to?

Reason I ask is I want to run some JavaScript in the console of firebug to see what CSS various selector will return

Comment: um... wut? What do you mean by a javascript api? Just... type javascript into the console....?

Comment: Please be more specific and tell us more, have no idea what you want to do.

Comment: You can run any Javascript you want in the console. In this case : `document.querySelectorAll('your[special="selector"].goes.here');`

Comment: There is not "CSS [for a] various selector" *without* being in context of a particular element. This is because selectors rely on *document position* as well as attributes like class/id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle):

> getComputedStyle() gives the final used values of all the CSS properties of an element.

eg:
`window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('header'));`